# Get mysql results in Rails, but formatted like in MySql client interface

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 2.2.2 with the Mysql gem v 2.7.  If I launch the MySql client from my terminal, and do a query, I get a table of results like this:

```
mysql> show indexes from lesson_units;
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| lesson_units |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | id          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| lesson_units |          1 | index_lesson_units_on_user_id |            1 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The interface methods in Rails generally do the most useful thing, eg returning the above data as an array of hashes, such as

```
#in Rails console
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("show indexes from lesson_units")
=> [{"Index_comment"=>"", "Sub_part"=>nil, "Key_name"=>"PRIMARY", "Comment"=>"", "Collation"=>"A", "Table"=>"lesson_units", "Packed"=>nil, "Seq_in_index"=>"1", "Index_type"=>"BTREE", "Null"=>"", "Cardinality"=>"2", "Non_unique"=>"0", "Column_name"=>"id"}, {"Index_comment"=>"", "Sub_part"=>nil, "Key_name"=>"index_lesson_units_on_user_id", "Comment"=>"", "Collation"=>"A", "Table"=>"lesson_units", "Packed"=>nil, "Seq_in_index"=>"1", "Index_type"=>"BTREE", "Null"=>"YES", "Cardinality"=>"2", "Non_unique"=>"1", "Column_name"=>"user_id"}]
```

Now, in terms of actually doing stuff with the data, this is great.  But, sometimes I'd like to just have a mysql-style view - eg, to get that first table back as text, which I can just print out.  Is this possible, via Rails? ie, to call a function which gives me back this string?

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.methodname_here("show indexes from lesson_units")
=> "+--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+\n    | Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |\n    +--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+\n    | lesson_units |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | id          | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |\n    | lesson_units |          1 | index_lesson_units_on_user_id |            1 | user_id     | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |\n    +--------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+\n    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)"
```

Comment: You can use this gem: https://github.com/aptinio/text-table

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov thanks but it's actually a bit awkward to get the data out of mysql into a table:  I can get the rows data with `.select_rows`  but that doesn't include the column headers.

Comment: Ok, understood. P.s. for text_rable you can include headers with `(first_row_is_head: true)`.

Comment: @MichaelArkhipov sorry, i mean that it's a bit awkward to get an array from sql where the first row is the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [`table_print`](https://github.com/arches/table_print) before which is pretty handy in `development`, so you can try something like below:

```
# Gemfile
group :development, :test do
  gem 'table_print'
end
```

**`rails c`**

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('show indexes from lesson_units;')

tp result.to_a
TABLE        | NON_UNIQUE | KEY_NAME                      | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULL | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT
-------------|------------|-------------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|--------------
lesson_units | 0          | PRIMARY                       | 1            | id          | A         | 0           |          |        |      | BTREE      |         |              
lesson_units | 1          | index_lesson_units_on_comment | 1            | comment     | A         | 0           |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |
```